# Express and MongoDB, problem with escape characters in the collection.find while using $text and $search

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

as from the MongoDB documentation,

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "\"coffee shop\"" } } )
```

would need to insert its escape characters in the collection.find into a variable named query belonging to req.query.name! so, that [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#index-feature-text) can be used.

```
var query = req.query.name;

collection.find({ $text: { $search: '"\"' + query + '\""'}})
```

I also tried

```
'"\"query\""'
```

unfortunately what I expected does not work, do you have any solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using [ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Try this:

```js
var query = `"${req.query.name}"`;

collection.find({ $text: { $search: query}})
```

OR

```js
var query = '"' + req.query.name + '"';

collection.find({ $text: { $search: query}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that it doesn't follow the index, so the query would be very slow. Without anything instead it runs which is a beauty!

Comment: i also tried with regex but in the same way it follows the index only with '^' and so i can't find the end of the string!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will help to make the same query as it is mentioned in Mongodb documentation. and it will use your index as well.

```
var value = `\\"${query}\\"`;
collection.find({ $text: { $search: value}})
```

and if by any chance, your outer double quotes are missing, then try this:

```
var value = `"\\"${query}\\""`
collection.find({ $text: { $search: value}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, nothing to do is not able to follow the index! from the mongo shell works perfectly! in express it fails, returning from debug(as you suggested): `"\\" coffee shop \\ ""` 
while in the shell everything works fine `$search: "\"coffee shop\""`

Comment: I forgot, if I initialize the variable in the following way: `var value = "\"coffee shop\""` everything works fine even in express but unfortunately I don't need the word coffee shop to search for;)